# How do you pass a variable to new js file function

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

Using ASP.NET MVC.  When my details button is clicked, I need to load a new details page and either 1. use the id of the item click to do an ajax call or 2. pass this information over to the details page. Not sure how to accomplish this.

I've tried doing an onclick call in a new function then window.location.href and ajax call right after but this fails.  When the new page is loaded the ajax does not run.

```
        $.each(carsList, function (index, cars) {
            var rCars = '<div class="col-md-12 card"><div class="card-body">'
            rCars += "<p>"+ cars.Year + " " + cars.Make + " " + cars.Model +"</p>"
            rCars += "<img src=" + cars.Photo + " width='100%' style='float: left;'>" + "<p style='text-align: center;'>" + " BodyStyle: " + cars.BodyStyle +
                " Interior Color: " + cars.IntColor + "$" + cars.SalePrice + "</p>"
            rCars += "<p style='text-align: center;'>" + "Trans: " + cars.Trans + " Mileage: " + cars.Mileage + " MSRP: " + cars.MSRP + "</p>"
            rCars += "<p style='text-align: center;'>" + "Color: " + cars.ExtColor + " #VIN: " + cars.VIN + "<button onclick=window.location.href='Details'>Details</button>"
            rCars += '</div>'
            rCars += '</div>'
            list.append(rCars);
        })
```

When the button is clicked it will load a new page.  I need to then pass in the variable cars.VehicleId so I can do an ajax call on the specific vehicle with this id.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to go to a different view with a parameter, you can try this: `onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Details", "ControllerName",new { id = cars.id}) + "'");"`

Comment: Please share more codes